# A diabolical puzzle: Hector + Tisiphone =?

Tags: calculation-puzzle, word, enigmatic-puzzle

Homer + Ovid = Paris

Ulysses + Julius Caesar =  Nimrod

Guy de Montfort - Cleopatra = Medusa

Epicurus - Pluto = Dido

Hector + Tisiphone = ***?***

Comment: Another brilliant puzzle! +1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My answer is

> Minotaur

Because

> **The main idea is to associate every name with its corresponding Circle number in Dante's Inferno (Divine Comedy).**

For example,

> Homer and Ovid both belong to the first Circle, while Paris belongs to the second: $1+1=2$.
>
>  Hector is in the first, Tisiphone between the fifth and sixth,

so the result must be

> between the sixth and the seventh Circle.

The only creature that satisfies that condition is

> the Minotaur, who's the guardian of the seventh Circle.

Extra:

> *the title says "diabolical", which is a reference to Inferno.*

Note: *my previous answer was Pier della Vigna, which is wrong.*